# Regarding calculating the summary statistics for each group in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have one dataframe having the columns such as following

```
ID                               Time                          Price
1002                     1998-01-02                    34
2001                     1998-02-03                   45
1002                     1998-04-05                    23
2003                      1998-02-03                   30
1002                       1998-02-03                   60
```

Based on this dataframe, I would like to create another dataframe, which has three columns, “`ID`”, “`period-1`”, “`period-2`”. Each entry is the mean value of the ID in the corresponding time period)

The new dataframe should look like as following. How to do that in Pandas?

```
ID                period-1(1998-01-01:1998-02-01)             period 2(1998-02-02-1998-05-02)
1002     
2001
2003
```

Here is the code that I got as suggested, but with some error

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["1002", "2001", "1002", "2003", "1002"],
                "Time": ["1998-01-02", "1998-02-03", "1998-04-05", "1998-02-03", "1998-02-03"],
                 "Price": ["34", "45", "23", "30","60"]})


df.Time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
period2=pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('1998-02-02'), pd.Timestamp('1998-05-02'), closed='both')
df['Price'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['New']='period1'


df.loc[df.Time.apply(lambda x : x in period2),'New']='period2'


df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='New',values='Price',aggfunc='mean')


 306             # people may try to aggregate on a non-callable attribute

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1304         nv.validate_groupby_func('mean', args, kwargs, ['numeric_only'])
   1305         try:
-> 1306             return self._cython_agg_general('mean', **kwargs)
   1307         except GroupByError:
   1308             raise

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   3972                             min_count=-1):
   3973         new_items, new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(
-> 3974             how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count)
   3975         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(new_items, new_blocks)
   3976 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   4044 
   4045         if len(new_blocks) == 0:
-> 4046             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
   4047 
   4048         # reset the locs in the blocks to correspond to our

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Interval` with `pivot_table`

```
#df.Time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

period2=pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('1998-02-02'), pd.Timestamp('1998-05-02'), closed='both')


df['New']='period1'

df.loc[df.Time.apply(lambda x : x in period2),'New']='period2'

df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='New',values='Price',aggfunc='mean')
Out[881]: 
New   period1  period2
ID                    
1002     34.0     41.5
2001      NaN     45.0
2003      NaN     30.0
```

Comment: Hi Wen, thanks for your answer, but I do not quite understand, the two lines , 

df['New']='period1'

df.loc[df.Time.apply(lambda x : x in period2),'New']='period2' , where is the definition of 'period 1', and are you trying to define a new column "new" with period1? Thanks.

Comment: @user288609 yes define new column

Comment: @Wen, I updated the original post with the code, and it has some error, also I am not quite understand how does your solution let period1 get into play. It seems to me that there is no information defined related to period 1 except creating a new column of period 1. I am kind of confused, thanks.